# Countable topology on $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Problem 4.25

Let T be the collection of all subsets $U \subset [0, 1]$ such
that $[0, 1] − U $ is countable, together with the empty set.

1. Prove that T is a topology on $[0, 1]$.

$\emptyset\in \mathcal T$ and if we delete no points from $[0,1]$ then $X\in\mathcal T$.

Let $\cup_\alpha U_\alpha$ be open sets, then $U_\alpha=X-G_\alpha$ where $F_\alpha$ is at most countable.

So we have that $\cup_\alpha U_\alpha=\cup (X-F_\alpha)=X-\cap_\alpha F_\alpha$, however $\cap_{\alpha} F_\alpha \subset F_\alpha$ is countable so topology.

2. Find the closure of $(0, 1]$.

Seems to just be $[0,1]$ quite honestly i was too lazy to prove this as it is obvious clearly it is not closed and it is a subset of $[0,1]$ consider if $(0, 1] \subset [a,1]$ where $a>0 $ assume this is the smallest closed set, consider $[\frac{a}{2},1] $  since $a>0$ we have that $\frac {a}{2} >0 $ this is a contradiction so leads us to $ a\leq 0 $  but $a<0$ is nonsense.

3. Prove that there is no sequence in $(0, 1]$ which converges to $0$.

i did eventually get this question and i still believe posted answer is wrong. $U=[0,1] / \{x_1,x_2,... \}$ then $ U^c =\{x_1,x_2,... \} $ is countable so $U\in \mathcal T $ but U does not contain any infinite tail of the sequence! so not only does the sequence not converge to 0 it appears that no sequence converges to anything.

Edit: This question has correct solutions to all three part of the problem (not just attempts) not sure how it was closed for lack of information given by OP

Comment: Hint: if you have such a sequence, it is sufficient to find an open set which contains 0 but does not contain any element of the sequence.

Comment: More hints: the co-countable topology pays no respect to the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. To the co-countable topology, $0$ is no more special to $(0, 1]$ than $\pi$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler if a sequence converges there must be infinitly many points in any open neighbourhood of the point which can be true when there are countably infinitly many in each ball around 0?

Comment: @Faust I feel weird explaining this to a member whose been here for 5 years, but the vote to close was likely because the person didn't feel that sufficient evidence of your attempts was included. It wasn't me, but I'm guessing that this person wanted to see your answer to question 1, some reason why you thought the answer to question 2 was $[0, 1]$, and they wanted to see some attempt made at question 3. I personally think it's a little harsh, but that's my best guess.

Comment: @TheoBendit But he _did_ write the answer to question 1.

Answer (score 2):

2. The answer is $\mathbb{R}$. Any uncountable subset will indeed be dense, as an open set can only exclude countably many points, and thus must contain at least some points in the uncountable subset.
3. Suppose $(x_n) \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n \to 0$ in under the co-countable topology, but $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n$. Then the range of $(x_n)$ is countable, so its complement is open. This is an open set, containing $0$, which fails to intersect the sequence. But, if $x_n \to 0$, then infinitely many terms of $x_n$ should lie in every open neighbourhood of $0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: How can the answer in 2) be $\mathbb R$?!

Comment: yeah i really think u mean $[0,1]$

Comment: I don't want to rush into rolling back an edit, but I genuinely think the answer to 2. is $\mathbb{R}$. As I pointed out in the comments under the question, $0$ is not special to $(0, 1]$ under the co-countable topology, and as I explained in my answer, any uncountable set will be **dense**, meaning its closure is the whole space $\mathbb{R}$. Think about it: $[0, 1]$ is not closed, since its complement is not open, since $[0, 1]$ is not countable.

Comment: I'm just going to roll back the edit. If you disagree, please feel free to down-vote and post your own answer. :-P

Comment: @bof Nicely put.

Comment: The closure cannot be $\mathbb R$ for the very simple reason that the topological space we are talking about had underlying set the interval [0,1], as the question clearly states.

Comment: The question doesn't involve a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but a topology on $[0,1]$.